# Looking for a UK (?) comic series, in which giant humanoid barbarians invade earth (from space)

Tags: story-identification, comics, alien-invasion

Really sure it's a UK series, don't know if it was originally published in 2000AD and then published as individual issues later?
It had airbrushed covers with UFOs and such. the Cover art was cool, but I remember the covers not seeming to have much relevance to the comic.
It was a color comic series.
Giants invade earth, they looked human but huge barbarians. I think fought with melee weapons(?) smashing up tanks and such.

The back story was that the giants were attacked in the past by huge war machines and they found out they were piloted by tiny aliens, so they distrusted smaller races because they knew small ones were clever.
The main giant had a wife.

There were other aliens they had conquered of various sizes. After one battle they questioned a human general who was asking "why they were doing all this" and their translator, a smaller alien was lying, saying the human general was being rude and would never surrender.

Edit: I was asked how old the comics were, I believe it was the 90's

Comment: Can you give a timeframe for when you read this comic and/or when it might have been published?